# Arduino function absolute of array?

Tags: c, arduino

My Code Is working great and give the output on the serial monitor until I add this function
call its stops sending to serial !!

the function fill the result array with the absolute values for the input array.

```
#define INPUT_SIZE 800

void vabs(double *vec,int vsize,double *result){
  int i;
  for(i=0 ; i<vsize ; ++i)
    result[i] = fabs(vec[i]);
}

double x1[INPUT_SIZE];
int x1size;
double absX1[INPUT_SIZE];
int absX1size;

double Process(int *inputArray,double *qrs){
  int i;

  // Initialization
  for(i=0 ; i<INPUT_SIZE ; ++i)
    x1[i] = (double)inputArray[i];

  x1size = INPUT_SIZE;
  // Cancellation DC drift and normalization
  double meanValue = mean(x1,x1size);
  minus(x1,x1size,meanValue);

  Serial.println(x1[0]);

//  vabs(x1,x1size,absX1);  // Uncomment this line will cause the problem!
  absX1size = x1size;
  *qrs = 5;
  return 10;
}
```

The setup & loop:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop(){
  // This array contains 800 values
  int bArr[]= {59,259,259,250,250,250,83,83,...};
  double qrs = 0;
  double heartRate = Process(bArr,&qrs);
  delay(5000);
}
```

I'm using Arduino Mega (Atmega1280) which has Flash Memory 128 KB And SRAM 8 KB.

Comment: I suspect you want `fabs` rather than `abs`. But regardless, can you be more specific about your problem? What happens?

Comment: aha,, when I use this function the serial monitor doesn't print anything !!

Comment: abs - for integers. fabs - for floats/doubles

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: i edit it,, but the same problem !

Comment: and in your for loop, shouldn't it be i++ instead of ++i?

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: its included ;)

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto: whats the difference in using ++i or i++ ??!!

Comment: I didn't even know that ++i works. I found this though: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/90811-plusplusi-vs-iplusplus-whats-difference.html wich, for your problem, don't make any difference.

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto - in this context, `++i` and `i++` do the same thing: they increment the value of `i`. They're interchangeable in code that doesn't use the value of the expression. That is, `int j = i++;` and `int j = ++i;` do two different things. But in the loop, the result of the increment isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `fabs()` try `(result[i] < 0 ? vec[i] * -1 : vec[i])`, this will show you if there is a problem in `fabs()`.

Side note, there seems to be a lot of unneeded code in here. I'm going to assume that is because you deleted other parts for posting on here.

Comment: I've tried this, but had the same problem,, nothing on the serial monitor !

Comment: Are you getting the output from `Serial.println(x1[0]);`?

Comment: aha,, from this statement :)